# How do I get crisp edges on Image Editor? (Get rid of fall off of stroke)

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

How can I get rid of the fall off and have sharp endings to my strokes when being in the Image Editor? I don't like how the brush kind of fades off the color at the edges, I want it to be crisp and one constant shade of the color I am using. [**Here**](https://gyazo.com/350ea7e58bdda716dd36eb5b691818ca) is what I mean. Do you see towards the bottom the edges have those shades of black? I want that to be a straight black edge of one shade, similar to towards the top.

The way I was able to get it to be a straight black edge is by coloring over the edges with the same color as the background, that's really annoying so I was wondering if you guys have any idea of accomplishing the same with the strokes. I remember having done this at some point before but I can't seem to be able to get that same effect anymore. In conclusion, I want a stroke that doesn't fade out at the edges and has one constant shade of the color throughout it, sort of like pixel painting with the same color rather than having a strength/brush-like feel to the strokes. And I am using a constant fall off, so it doesn't make sense how this is happening still. Is it the spacing? I can't seem to make that less than 1%.

*Thanks,*

*Best regards,*

*Idealist Developer*

Comment: I am thinking this is due to settings for aliasing, but are you using pressure on strength as well?

Answer (score 0):

In the brush properties, go into the falloff menu. The curve you see is the intensity of the brush starting from the center and traveling outwards. Right now the curve is sloping downwards to the right, meaning that the intensity of the brush will be very intense in the middle, then will gradually decrease based on the curve. It will make more sense once you play with the curve a bit.

To change this, just change the graph so all the control points are on max height. Or, click the preset on the bottom which looks like a bracket. (It does the same thing)

[image]

(Something I drew)

[image: Something I drew hehehe]